# Cocoon + Rails—how to access object data on form error (for dynamic fields)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cocoon-gem

I have cocoon creating association sub-forms, one of these forms has `projects` and `codes`

#### Setup

```
/ view (in slim format)
.nested-fields.subform.project-subform
  = link_to_remove_association "×", f
  #project-code-container
    .form_group
      = f.label :project_id, "Project"
      = f.select(:project_id,
        @current_projects.map { |project| [project.name, project.id] },
        {},
        { onChange: "updateCodes(this)" },
        )
    .form_group
      = f.label :project_code_id, "Code"
      = f.select(:project_code_id, @current_project_codes[1])
```

The second select should show a list of codes based on the index of the selected project. So if project `3` was selected, then the options for codes should be `@current_project_codes[3]`

#### Problem

When I hit a validation error on submit, the form is reloaded with the previous data already filled out (like a normal rails form). However, I don't know how to tell the `project_code` select which options it should load. Since this is a cocoon form, I don't have an object like `@project` to access the data.

I need to figure out what `project` was selected, so I can show the right codes.

**On validation error/reload, how can I get a cocoon object's data?**

*p.s. I'm struggling to define this question, if you have ideas on how to make my question clearer, please let me know.*

Comment: You can do `f.object.project` to get the selected project

Comment: Can you show us the associations/relations? What is the relation between projects and codes? (is there a fixed list of projects and for each project there is a fixed list of codes? Can I compare this with a kind of user-project relation, where a user is assigned different projects, and within such an assignment a possible role (and not all projects have the same roles available?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Credit to @arieljuod

`f.object` gives the form's object with its data

For my specific problem, this was the line that allowed a select to autopopulate with any pre-saved data:

```
f.select(
  :project_code_id, 
  @current_project_codes[f.object.project_id || @current_projects.first.id]
)
```